# Create GitHub Action step output in TypeScript Code

Tags: typescript, github-actions

Is there a way to create a step output from inside a code snippet that is executed by a GitHub Action step?
My step is running  a CDK deploy (TypeScript) command and I'd like to create some GHA outputs from the TypeScript code.

I tried using the code snippet below in TypeScript, but this did not create the outputs I expected:

```
const accessKey = new CfnAccessKey(this, 'testserKey', {
  userName: testUser.userName,
});

core.setOutput('devSecret', accessKey.attrSecretAccessKey);
```

This is how I'd like to use it in GH Actions:

```
  # step that should create the output
  - name: Run CDK deploy
    id: run-cdk
    run: cdk deploy --all --require-approval=never 
  
  # step that should use it
  - name: Use variable value
    run: echo ${{ steps.run-cdk.outputs.devSecret }}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using actions/toolkit properly?
You should use core.setOutput to make output available for further use.
Just like in example shown over [here](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/blob/00282d61458d99f725588a9463b9d25dfda51c22/packages/core/README.md).

Comment: Tried adding it this way:     `core.setOutput(Value, value)`, but it does not work unfortunately.

Comment: Well, it's nice to see some more details after you've edit OP... It's also nice that now you are using `actions/toolkit` but to locate the problem i'm afraid you will need to show more details of your solution because on this stage we don't even know how your logs looks like.

Comment: The logs suggest the variable is not created or is not created at the right place. I'm creating it inside the CDK code, so maybe it's created in a complete different place. Not sure what else I can show.

Comment: I would suggest to use a bottom-up approach of solving problems.
Simply first check if everything is ok with your script - debug it. 
Next check your cdk setup.  Does your script works properly in manual/managed launch?
Last check gh actions setup. Does your workflow config installs cdk properly? You can also [enable debug logging](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/enabling-debug-logging) and analyze it.

Comment: Yeah, it works correctly. I added a GHA step to see if the output file is created with --out-file and piped back it's output to another step, that works. The only thing that is not working is the core.setOutput().

Comment: Okay, I managed to find the issue. Now the problem is, when I try to retrive the value of the output variable I ccreated, it return Token[TOKEN.233] instead of the value I expect.

Comment: You are reciving [token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/tokens.html) cause you are probably before prepare phase of [app lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/apps.html#lifecycle).
Try using [cfnOutput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_core.CfnOutput.html) before passing to actions output.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is, the output contains secrets and CfnOutput prints it in the log. Do you know any way to mask/hide it?